# In revtex, how can I quote a integrated figure without sub-figure and make the generated hyperlink show as "Fig. 1(a)"?

Tags: revtex

How can I quote a integrated figure without sub-figure and make the generated hyperlink show as

> Fig. 1(a)

in a RevTex documentclass, just like other [published papers](https://i.loli.net/2019/06/12/5d00712a19c6125735.png):

[image]

My code is

```
\documentclass[preprint,prl,aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
 \includegraphics[width=8cm]{1}
   \caption{ \label{fig:a}(a) is the first part of the figure. \label{fig:b}(b) is the second \dots}
\end{figure}
In Fig.~\ref{fig:a}(a) we \dots
In Fig.~\ref{fig:b}(b) we \dots
\end{document}
```

Compiled results

[image]

I want to "1(a)" be blue as a hyperlink, not just "1".

Comment: Consider accepting one of the provided answers.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\autoref`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering     
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption a.}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption a.}
        \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}     
\caption{Overall caption.}
\end{figure}

In \autoref{fig:a} we \dots
\end{document}
```

[image]

If you use `cleveref`, use the `nameinlink` option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering     
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{Caption a.}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure} 
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-b}
        \caption{Caption a.}
        \label{fig:b}
\end{subfigure}     
\caption{Overall caption.}
\end{figure}

In \Cref{fig:a} we \dots
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please allow me to clarify my problem. I can only include one picture, not like 2 pictures in your sample. And there is only one caption, without sub-caption, in compiled pdf file.

Comment: @KM If you replace the figure by `\begin{figure}[htb]
\centering     
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.48\linewidth}
\centering\includegraphics[width=4cm]{example-image-a}
        \caption{~}
        \label{fig:a}
    \end{subfigure} 
\caption{Overall caption.}
\end{figure}` it still works. BTW, I feel that this is a bit inefficient. You do not provide any TeX code, but then tell me mine is not what you want. How about you post some TeX code that others can use as a basis for an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the sublabels by hand.

```latex
\documentclass[preprint,prl,aps]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true, citecolor=blue, urlcolor=blue, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\includegraphics[width=8cm]{example-image}

\caption{(a) is the first part of the figure.(b) is the second \dots}
\label{fig:global}
\makeatletter
\let\save@currentlabel\@currentlabel
\edef\@currentlabel{\save@currentlabel(a)}\label{fig:a}
\edef\@currentlabel{\save@currentlabel(b)}\label{fig:b}
\makeatother
\end{figure}

In Fig.~\ref{fig:a} we \dots

In Fig.~\ref{fig:b} we \dots

\end{document}
```

[image]